# How can I throttle a Highland.js or Node.js stream to one object per second?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, highland.js

I'd like to be able to throttle the calls to `getPagerank()` to one per second.  I've tried various things but can't get it to work.

```
var pagerank = require('pagerank');
var _ = require('highland');

var urls = [
    'google.com',
    'yahoo.com',
    'bing.com'
];

var getPagerank = _.wrapCallback(pagerank);

// I want to throttle calls to getPagerank to 1/sec
var pageRanks = _(urls)
    .map(getPagerank)
    .merge();

pageRanks.toArray(function(arr) {
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.ratelimit()`

e.g. this will limit the stream to processing one item of the array per one second

```
var _ = require('highland');

_([1,2,3,4]).ratelimit(1, 1000).map(function(x){
  return String(x);
})
.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Comment: I thought I did a decent job of scanning the docs.  Guess not.  Thanks!